# Aligning on the same height two items using in CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm currently trying to align my text 'hello' with the pencil icon you see below. But apparently the pencil icon just wants to sit below the text.

Both the text and the icon are contained within a div with the following style:

```css
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
```

while the icon itself is a div with an icon inside of it, and the div has the following style applied to it:

```css
  width: 40px;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #88888850;
```

[image]

How can I move up the edit icon in order to match the top and bottom of the bordered container?

I created also an example in this snippet:

```css
.bordered-container {
    height: 50px;
    border: 1.5px solid #88888850;
    margin: 30px;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.edit-icon {
  width: 20px;
  opacity: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #88888850;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="bordered-container">
    <span class="title">Hello</span>
    <div class="edit-icon">
      EDIT
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Please make a simplified demo as a snippet in your question, not linking to an external code source.  There's no need to have an entire react application to be compiled just for a CSS question

Comment: You're right, I'll be right on it

Comment: Well, you haven’t set the display property for "bordered-container". That would be a good starting point. Maybe flex? or inherit, depending upon your setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try what I have below.  I've commented out a lot of stuff you didn't need and I marked what I've added.  Basally the container needs to be a flexbox, not the `edit-icon`.  Also if you don't define heights, things will just flow to the sizes they take up, and it require less code.

[this page](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is a really great resource on learning about Flexbox if you haven't seen it already.

```css
.bordered-container {
  /*height: 50px;*/
  border: 1.5px solid #88888850;
  margin: 30px;
  
  /* ADDED */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.edit-icon {
  /*width: 20px;
  opacity: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 50px;*/
  
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #88888850;
}
```

```html
<div class="bordered-container">
  <span class="title">Hello</span>
  <div class="edit-icon">
    EDIT
  </div>
</div>
```